# Split pdf into multiple pages preferably into its pages and save the various files in a folder using node js

Tags: node.js, pdf

Is it possible to split a pdf file into the number of pages it has and save these files in a folder using node js?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) this should be fairly simple. This code should help you get started, it still needs some error-handling of course:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdf-lib').PDFDocument;

async function splitPdf(pathToPdf) {

    const docmentAsBytes = await fs.promises.readFile(pathToPdf);

    // Load your PDFDocument
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(docmentAsBytes)

    const numberOfPages = pdfDoc.getPages().length;

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {

        // Create a new "sub" document
        const subDocument = await PDFDocument.create();
        // copy the page at current index
        const [copiedPage] = await subDocument.copyPages(pdfDoc, [i])
        subDocument.addPage(copiedPage);
        const pdfBytes = await subDocument.save()
        await writePdfBytesToFile(`file-${i + 1}.pdf`, pdfBytes);

    }
}

function writePdfBytesToFile(fileName, pdfBytes) {
    return fs.promises.writeFile(fileName, pdfBytes);
}

(async () => {
    await splitPdf("./path-to-your-file.pdf");
})();
```

Comment: @YoungDeveloper: Happy to help - it would be nice if you could accept my answer (click the checkmark next to my answer)

Comment: Can the pdf-lib package optimize the pdf document that has been split such that it optimizes any heavy images in the pdf?

Comment: Hello. i have a pdf file of size n = 2000 and i want to get page 10 to 100. how can we do this

Comment: I actually searched for this question because I need to use pdf-lib without loading the whole pdf into memory. Looks like I have to keep searching