# Split a PDF file based on size in KB if size more than specified limit using javascript, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to create a function that accepts the file path as input and then I need to check if it is pdf formate and its size is more than 800kb or not if yes then I have to split the file and have to return paths of file that are created. Can please help me with which library I can do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039152/split-pdf-in-separate-file-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62041207/split-pdf-into-multiple-pages-preferably-into-its-pages-and-save-the-various-fil

Comment: https://github.com/tcr/scissors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @DaveMeehan but can you please tell me how can get the size in kb of the file I know the only path of the file. I have done many google searches. please let me know

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of those solutions, that literally took 30 seconds of Googling which is what I suggest you could do to answer the question.  Not to mention that you have node's own file system calls to play with.